# How do you implement Background Tasks in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am reading through apple documentations for their background framework. I doun't understand where to place this code in a swiftUI project

```
  BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.apple-samplecode.ColorFeed.refresh", using: nil) { task in
         self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
    }
```

Comment: Here is the [WWDC 19 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-707/?time=996) where they do a walk through of this API.

Comment: Place that in the App's init() function.